# How to run Elasticsearch 5.2.1 as root user in linux machine

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to run Elasticsearch 5.2.1 in my linux machine which I am the root user of it.

When I tried to execute the Elasticsearch. I am getting the following error,

```
[2017-03-15T03:26:18,976][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elk_data1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:203) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.1.jar:5.2.1]
        ... 6 more
```

I tried this way also `bin/elasticsearch -Des.insecure.allow.root=true` but no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a **bad** idea so they rightfully decided to make it impossible. Get over it and run ES as a regular user. It's not so that because you are root you have to run everything as root, quite the contrary.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the possibility to run as root has been removed since Elasticsearch 5.0, as mentioned in that [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18688) and [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-1-1-cannot-run-as-root-user/70304/7).

If you really want to run as root (I guess you are aware it is not the best idea), I would suggest checking out the source code from github, and modify that [specific line](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java#L103), then rebuild the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

See this Pull request：[Remove allow running as root - GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18694/files)

Sine 2 Jun 2016, you could not run elasticsearch as root unless rebuilding the elasticsearch.

Reference files:
[elasticsearch/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/bootstrap/Bootstrap.java#L101-L104)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, in my case I used package-manager (dpkg) to install elasticsearch and I were trying to run it directly from elasticsearch's bin directory but it had to be started as service using following command

```
systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```